# Install problem for DWA-131 E on Linux generic 4.4.x (16.04)

Tags: kernel

Have DWA-131 E wifi which previously worked with all previous generic versions of Linux under 14.04. That is, I had no problem with `make` and `sudo make install`, and my wifi link worked fine.

Installed 16.04 today, and, when I tried `make` in generic 4.4.x, I got errors which seemed to be centered on null values being not allowed. The first lines of the error are here:

```
In function ‘dump_drv_version’:
/home/richard/Dropbox/UbuntuDesktopStuff/DWA-131_Linux_drive‌​r_v4.3.1.1/20140812_‌​rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3‌​.1.1_11320/include/r‌​tw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be #define _seqdump seq_printf
/home/richard/Dropbox/UbuntuDesktopStuff/DWA-131_Linux_drive‌​r_v4.3.1.1/20140812_‌​rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3‌​.1.1_11320/include/r‌​tw_debug.h:240:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’ if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
```

So I went back to a 3.x.x generic version (still under 16.04 it seems), and I have wifi access again. So it seems that the problem is with the 4.x.x generic Linux versions.

Any way to get around this? Or do I just have to go back to the 3.x.x version when I start up each day!?

Comment: What software do you "make"?

Comment: Downloaded Linux software for the DWA-131 E from the Internet. Folder used for the make is: 20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320, along with another folder: wpa_supplicant_hostapd-0.8_rtw_r7475.20130812.

Comment: Connect by wire and use my answer to install the driver

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

This is the same driver packed and patched for Ubuntu.